# How can you add vertical line for data point in the new Microsoft Charting Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

So I am using this fancy new charting control.
[More info here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)

I have data displayed already. What I want to do is add a line seperator that is there every year. Basically vertical red line on every jan, 1st?

Any ideas??? Data points do not exist for each day in the year. It can be anywhere from 365 to 1 data point in between two year seperators.

I tried going over sample but did not get any useful idea.
Anyone?

So I found that they have StripLine

```
Stripline stripLine = new StripLine();
```

I wonder how can I add this to a point. Not to make it repeat automatically. Anyone?

Just to be clear I have a graph and while adding points as soon as I find a point that matches certain conditions I want to add strip line at that place as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might help for every January 1st:

```
StripLine stripLine = new StripLine();
stripLine.BackColor = Color.Red;
stripLine.IntervalOffset = 1; //how many days until Jan 1 from the start of the range? This is always relative to the data being displayed. 
stripLine.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days; //days in reference to the above question

stripLine.Interval = 60; //set a marker every 60 days
stripLine.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;  //in relation to comment above

stripLine.StripWidth = 1; //show the marker in a 1 day width
stripLine.StripWidthType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;  //in relation to comment above
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.StripLines.Add(stripLine);
```

Comment: the problem is it is not in regular intervals.
its once a year. But we might not have 365 data points for 2008. So I cant use regular interval of some value 60 or what not.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489216.aspx?ppud=4): "To draw a non-repeating strip line, set StripLine.Interval to a large number so that only one repeated instance fits on the chart."

Comment: The image is gone, if you still have it, can you upload it to Stack Exchanges imgur?

Comment: @rene it's such a shame that SO didn't partner with imgur from day 1. Sorry, I don't have it

Comment: @p.campbell I agree with that. As that image won't come back, will you edit the post to remove the link, recreate it or describe what was on the image?

Comment: i don't remember anymore but I will update the question